# Can I put custom settings in Django's settings.py

Tags: django, django-settings

I have several *custom* settings I'd like to define in my Django app. Up to this point, I've put them in a `constants.py` file in each individual app.

`myapp/constants.py`

```
HOURS_PER_EVENT = 4
MAX_MEMBERS_PER_EVENTS = 150
MAX_EVENTS_PER_YEAR = 10
...
```

It just occurred to me I may be able to put these in `settings.py` and after a quick test everything seems to work fine. Is this allowed or is `settings.py` reserved for core django settings defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/)? If it's not allowed, is there a better place to put these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is allowed to extend your application settings, and it is really simple to do it. All that you need to do is a simple manipulation from your current project `settings.py` to a module `settings`.

Your file structure is probably like the following:

```
mysite/
 |-- mysite/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

What you need to do is to change it to something like this:

```
mysite/
 |-- mysite/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- base.py  <-- (this is your old settings.py)
 |    |    +-- constants.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

This is a pattern described in [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html).

Comment: Do I have to break out my settings file into separate files or are you just recommending that as a best practice? My project seems to work fine by placing these values in the main settings file and I kind of like it that way.

Comment: @JohnnyMetz Sorry, didn't make myself clear at the beginning of my answer. Yes I'm recommending as a best practice. And yes, you can add these on your `settings.py` ;D